# How does PineScript parse 'if series1 > series2'?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to figure out how some of the code I've found written in PineScript works.

It's like this:

```
C_BlackBody = open > close
C_EngulfingBearish = C_UpTrend and C_BlackBody [...]
if C_EngulfingBearish
    [do something...]
```

What I wanted to do was put out the value of `close`.  `open` and `close` are both series, meaning that `C_BlackBody` and `C_EngulfingBearish` are too.  However, `C_EngulfingBearish` can successfully be used in an `if` statement, so it's acting like a single boolean.  Yet if I try to concatenate it into a string, it says it's still a series:

```
debugInfo := "Close: " + close
```

Gives the error:

```
Cannot call 'operator +' with arguments (literal string, series[float]);
```

So what is `close`, `C_EngulfingBearish`, and other series being evaluated as when used in an `if` statement, and how can this be transferred into a string so I can output it in a label as debug info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C_EngulfingBearish`  is a series of Boolean values so it can be used in the condition of the operator `if`.
Use the function `tostring` to convert to string.

```
debugInfo := "Close: " + tostring(close)
```

Read Tips for [Debagging](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Debugging.html)